# Python, disable warnings filter

Tags: python, warnings

How to disable the filtering of the warnings?

I would like to output several times the same warning, but a filter in the library avoids to output more than once the same warning.

```
import warnings

for i in range(2):
    warnings.warn("warning message")
```

output:

```
C:\Users\me\my_script.py:4: UserWarning: warning message
  warnings.warn("warning message")
```

The documentation is here:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html

Apparently I have to set `"always"` in the tuple at the entry of the filter, I don't know how to do so, and where to access this tuple.

Comment: did you try `warnings.simplefilter("always")`?

Comment: thank you, this is the line I was looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update warning filters with the [`warnings.simplefilter()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html#warnings.simplefilter) and [`warnings.filterwarnings()` functions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html#warnings.filterwarnings); from the module intro:

> The determination whether to issue a warning message is controlled by the warning filter, which is a sequence of matching rules and actions. Rules can be added to the filter by calling `filterwarnings()` and reset to its default state by calling `resetwarnings()`.

To make all warnings repeat beyond the first issue, use

```
warnings.simplefilter('always')
```

You can expand on this by adding more details to filter on. For example, your `warnings.warn()` calls do not specify a category, so the default then is to use [`warnings.UserWarning`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.UserWarning); you could add that to the filter:

```
warnings.simplefilter('always', warnings.UserWarning)
```

etc. You can use keyword arguments too if you only want to specify some of the filter arguments, such as `append=True`.

Answer (score 1):

With python 2.7.15rc1, to disable all warnings, I used these two lines of code:

```
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
```

I hope it is useful

Comment: I needed `"always"` but yes it helps :)